# How to read connection string in ASP .NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, connection, web-config

I can't wrap my head around how to retrieve connection strings in ASP .NET Core. I've spent two days trying all the different things and can't get it to work.

I have tried the following methods:

- Using **ConfigurationManager.AppSettings** a Count returns 0
- Using **ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[].ConnectionString** - the only connection string that exists is to .\SQLEXPRESS (have to use index rather than string in the ConnectionStrings[]), specifying a name of the connection results in object reference not set error
- Trying to use **WebConfigurationManager** can't find how to add it. I've tried System.Web.Configuration, NuGet packages, references.
- Using **IConfiguration and dependency injection** - I've got no idea how to read the connection string (how to reference the controller in the model and read the value of "xxx" connection string)

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SupplierDB"].ConnectionString
// NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString
// data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count.ToString();
// Returns 0
```

I've got same connection strings specified in both appsettings.json and web.config. Can someone please point me in the right direction as I'm currently completely lost as nothing works.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CustomerDB": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Customer_Db;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False",
    "SupplierDB": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Supplier_Db;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CustomerDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Customer_Db;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"/>
    <add name="SupplierDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Supplier_Db;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `AppSettings` class like this, by copying your appsettings.json to [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/):

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public static ConnectionStrings ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
    public static Logging Logging { get; set; }
    public static string AllowedHosts { get; set; }
}

public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string CustomerDb { get; set; }
    public string SupplierDb { get; set; }
}

public class Logging
{
    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; }
}

public class LogLevel
{
    public string Default { get; set; }
    public string Microsoft { get; set; }
    public string MicrosoftHostingLifetime { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `Startup`:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

I use `static` for easy access instead of injecting `AppSettings` through DI.

Or if you don't want to put them all in a class, check out the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the connection string value in appsettings.json like below:

For Mvc:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string CustomerDBConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomerDB");
        string SupplierDBConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SupplierDB");

        return View();
    }
}
```

For Razor Pages:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public IndexModel(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        string CustomerDBConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomerDB");
        string SupplierDBConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SupplierDB");
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I believe there is a newer way to do this without a cshtml or a code-behind

Comment: What does Startup.cs look like?

Answer (score -1):

Be sure you have the following NuGets installed:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
//Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets; //Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables;
```

- Generate the following class:

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

```
    public static class CustomConfiguration
        {
            public static IConfigurationRoot config;

            public static void BuildConfiguration()
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                    //.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    //.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                config = builder.Build();
            }
}
```

Then, call the Subject method from anywhere you like

```
    CustomConfiguration.BuildConfiguration();
    string connectionString = CustomConfiguration.config.GetConnectionString("CustomerDB");
```

Comment: where did you put the class?

Comment: This answer is incompatible with DotNet5 and DotNet6 Blazor.